# How to exclude packages from code coverage report?

Tags: android, android-espresso, jacoco

I currently am using the createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport to run my android instrumentation tests and generate a coverage report. The only issue that I am running into is that there are packages that are generated from Realm and Databinding and these classes are also being included in my coverage report. How can I configure jacoco to exclude these packages?

Answer (score 0):

```
test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
        excludes = []
    }
}
```

[Click here for more details on official Jacoco Gradle Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining the **`debugTree`** you can add the fileFilters to be excluded.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
 reports {
      xml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
 }
 def fileFilter = ['**/package/**']
 def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
}
```